# Is the "person defending trailerhome with a shotgun" a common scene?

Tags: trope

I have a feeling that there is a kind of scene, where you have a person that lives in a motorhome /trailer, and defends it against intruders by pointing a shotgun at the door.

I can think of two examples right now:

- In Loki Episode 3, this woman defends her home against trespassers by pointing a sci-fi shotgun at the door
  [image: Woman with sci-fi shotgun in Loki Episode 3]
- In Kill Bill vol.2, Budd defends his home from the Bride with a shotgun
  [image: Budd defends his home with a shotgun]

What I mean, is that kind of scene a known cinematographic trope? And if it is, do we know where it comes from?

Comment: I'd suspect it's from long before cinema, it's a cultural 'meme' - back to the 'trope', for want of a better word, that all Americans [can] own guns & are quite likely to point them at people trying to break in; be it a wooden shack in 1842 or a trailer in 2005.

Comment: ^ Ya, I would think you would see it a lot in 'golden age' Westerns...

Comment: If you broad the scope of "people defending their home (whatever the type) with a gun of any kind" you would get lots of more examples, specially in USA productions. Then you consider "trailers and motorhomes being more frequent outside cities" and "people from the countryside having shotguns because they serve as hunting weapons", then the coincidence is far from strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reckon it harkens back to America’s roots as a frontier nation.

In 1862, Congress passed the [**Homestead Act**](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Homestead-Act), which granted ownership of up to 160 acres of western land to any citizen willing to build and maintain a farm there for five years.

“Homesteaders” relied on their rifles not just for hunting food, but also for home defense.

[image: historical photo of an American homestead]

[Image Source](https://www.nps.gov/teachers/classrooms/upload/Lesson-Plan-3-Life-on-the-Homestead-pdf.pdf)

Certain aspects of the homestead ideal continue today in rural America among those who wish to live “off the grid”, such as in [this blog post](https://anamericanhomestead.com/the-importance-of-the-homestead-rifle/) entitled “The Importance of the Homestead Rifle”.

The website “TV Tropes” also notes [shotguns](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShotgunsAreJustBetter) as “the weapon of choice for **farmers, mountain men, hillbillies,** and other **rural folks**”.

See also their pages on “[**overprotective fathers**](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OverprotectiveDad)” and “[**shotgun weddings**](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShotgunWedding)” (the latter of which is also recognized by [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/shotgun_marriage) as an idiom).